# How to set value with set value function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="<?php echo set_value   ('template',$temp); ?>" />


  public function index($id=NULL)
 {
    if(empty($id)){
     redirect('service');
    }else{
   $this->load->model('servicemodel');
$pro = $this->servicemodel->get_pro_info($id);  
if($pro){
    $this->load->helper('form');
        $data['temp']=$pro['0']['name'];
    $data['page']="buynow/userform";
    $this->load->view('buynow/paymentindia',$data);        }  


    public function user_validation()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");
    if ($this->form_validation->run('uservalidation')){

         // validation success
    }else{

          $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('buynow/paymentindia',$data);
    }
  }
```

I want to fill data in set value, an error comes on undefined `$temp`

My form is in different function but validation is in different function, when we any error occur in validation `$temp` showing undefined variable.

Comment: function means controller ?

Comment: Yes function means controller

Comment: pass the value by assigning to  `$temp` from controller, update your question with controller code

Comment: Thanks for input... set_value should be properly implement otherwise always have trouble

Comment: may I see code in detail

Comment: code updated please help

Comment: Please use as  <?php echo set_value('field_name'); ?>, show html field name inside braces instead variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose here is your controller

```
public function registerForm(){
  //you have to pass a value to $temp
  $data[temp] = '101';
  $this->load->view('register',$data);
}
```

now you will get the value on your register.php view file

you are not passing any value to $temp after validation fail

use following code

```
public function user_validation()
{
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");
   if ($this->form_validation->run('uservalidation')){
     // validation success
   }else{
      // you have to pass value again to $temp
      $data['temp'] = $this->input->post('template');
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('buynow/paymentindia',$data);
   }
 }
```

Comment: `$data['temp']=$pro['0']['name'];` remove single quote of 0

Comment: id value pass in url and this id value get `$temp` variable value using model from database .in second function data validation `$id` value goes automatic null because function is different

Comment: value is working fine but when validation fail this is showing undefined variable

Comment: so I want to use  `set_value ()` function here.

Comment: use updated code, updated  `else` part of your function